# how to create a directory in iphone settings in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, download, directory

I am new programmer in objective c. I want to create "Download" directory inside the i phone(path : setting (i phone setting directory))I want to know is it possible?. I am using i phone simulator to test the program.

Another question is, How can I access created directory in i phone simulator. Below contains code I tried to create folder in i phone. But I can not access that directory by using i phone simulator. what the wrong of this code?

```
NSString *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Test"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create Directory in to Document Directory as sub Folder like this way:-

```
-(IBAction)CreatDirInDocDir
{

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *dir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",DirName];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dir];

    NSError *error;

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:path ] == YES){

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"File not found");

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }


}
```

when ever you create directory in to Document directory folder then you can get all list of Created Custom directory like this way:-

```
//Get all Directory

 NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

    NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);

    NSMutableArray *directoryList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for ( NSString *direPath in filePathsArray )
    {
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:direPath];
        BOOL isDir = NO;
        [fileMan fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:(&isDir)];
        if(isDir) {
            NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
            NSLog(@"log path ==%@",fullPath);
            [directoryList addObject:fullPath];
        }
    }
```

> NSLog(@"list path ==%@",directoryList);

Now you have array of all directory you can get any directory with index :)
Hope its helps you

Comment: How can I sow this created directory in i phone ? @Nitin

Comment: check now hope its helps you :)

Comment: Yeah! I got idea from this. but I have simple problem. Why we cannot see that created directory in i phone ?

Comment: @Gayan we can print directory path while run project in device wea xcode but we can not reach folder in iphone like simulator or xcode so dont wory its working fine as simulator

Answer (score 2):

All The method posted here are correct and there are tons of answers about them, but I'd like to warn you about a concept. Since The introduction of iCloud, Apple started to reject applications that saves a lot of data in document directory, when they are used by means of caches or they could be downloaded again later. The problem here is that you can backup your ios devices on the cloud and document directory is one of the backupped. Can you image yourself backupping one GB on application on the cloud? That's the explanation about apple rejects.
  To avoid that temp/redownloadable/cached data should be saved in cache directory. This useful dir is freed when the device is running out of space on "disk", like when you try to install a new app and you don't have enough space. So this is ok if your data can be downloaded again and are not indispensable. 
 the other way around is to keep data in the document directory but telling the system to do not backup them, this is possible adding a special flag to the doc subdirectory where you saved the file, here is how [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) , pay attention that this methods is only available from 5.0.1 so you need to check its existence if you target lower ioses. In this case the system will not free your data and not backup them this is safe for apple guidelines. 
 hope this helps

Comment: valuable answer. Actually I am a new programmer to objective C. Before I did C#.net .

Answer (score 1):

For creating directory you can use:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test"];
NSError *error;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error])
{
     NSLog(@"Couldn't create directory error: %@", error);
}
```

For getting the files inside that directory you can use:

```
NSArray *datArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:&error];
if(error)
{
     NSLog(@"Could not get list from directory, error = %@",error);
}
```

Here all file names will be in the `datArray`.

Answer (score 0):

No need append '/' . Just Use

```
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test"];
```

Try This

```
 NSArray *dirPath;
NSString *docsDir;
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPath objectAtIndex:0];

if ([filemgr changeCurrentDirectoryPath: docsDir] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"Error");
}else {
    NSString *currentPath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",currentPath);
}

NSString *dataDirectory = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test"];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:dataDirectory]){
        NSLog(@"dir Exist");
    }else{
NSLog(@"Creating Dir");
[filemgr createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone want to show your created directory in i phone simulator follow bellow steps :

1. Go to finder
2. Click Command +Shift + g
3. Type ~/Library then click Go
4. Open Application Support --> i phone simulator

Then you can find your created applications and directories..